# How to filter and merge data from multiple sheets using excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, excel-2007

I have an excel file with 3 sheets. File can be downloaded from [here](https://www.excelguru.ca/forums/showthread.php?11485-Excel-filter-and-merge-multiple-sheets-into-one&p=47474#post47474)

sample sheet looks like below

[image]

From all the 3 sheets, I would like to copy only rows with criteria `Product = X` and put it in one final sheet.

3 sheet names are sheet1,sheet2,sheet3. Is there any formula that you can help me with?

I am unable to attach a sample excel file in stack overflow.

Currently am doing this manually. Can you help?

Answer (score -1):

You could use a power query (connection only) to get the data from each of the 3 sheets, then do a union (append) power query of those 3 connection only sources into a new query and return the data to a table on another sheet.
[Get the combine/append query here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6TCAZ.png)
Clarification: you might want to turn your source data into tables first, which could be helpful if the range changes

Comment: thanks for the help. welcome to SO. Is there any excel formula that you can suggest? upvoted

Comment: Go through the process, 1. Turn the data into tables 2. For each of the 3 tables Data>From table/range 3. Plug in the criteria 4. Close and load to connection only 5. Data>Get data>Combine queries>Append (choose the 3 connections you just made)